# Bluetooth barcode scanner pairing problems

Tags: bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I have a Bluetooth barcode scanner which I've already paired up with a PC. It works fine but whenever I shutdown the PC and start it up again - for example the next day - it seems that the Bluetooth connection is lost. I can no longer scan barcodes and I have to pair it with the PC again to make it work again.

I'm not that familiar with Bluetooth, but isn't a Bluetooth device supposed to work even after you've shutdown the host PC?

Answer (score 1):

your barcode scanner probably only pair with your base station by default. So everytime you shut down your computer or the bar code scanner, you need to tell the bar code scanner to pair with the computer instead of the base station.